# Java: How do I create a list of a class from String

Tags: java, class, reflection

I want to create a list typed to the name of a class from a string.
For example,

```
String nameOfClass = "com.my.list.class";
List list = new ArrayList<nameOfclass>();
```

I only know the type of class to be inserted into List in runtime in text format.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need this... ?

Comment: You have to create instance of nameOfClass by reflection Class.forName() and then create a list for that class.

Comment: @prasanth at runtime it is a `List` of `Object`s.

Comment: @LCYSoft - i think you need to use class name at runtime and want to product object. am i right?

Comment: Why not just have a variable called `name` in the class and set it?

Comment: Right. I only know the type of class in runtime in text format

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

Generic type annotations only happen at compile-time, they are erased from the runtime. When the program executes, the ArrayList does not know about its generic type.

So as a result, the type annotation is only useful for the compiler. If you don't know the type at compile time (program design time), then you cannot use them.

Comment: If you give a bit more context for why you need this, we may come up with an alternative to that end.